# Cannot convert to JSONObject after updating array

Tags: android, json

I used to have a response string that I converted to JSONObject in this way:

```
JSONObject obj_temp = new JSONObject(response);
```

Then, I added to that string some modifications. At first, the index 'TripDetails' just had 1 trip with it details (trip information, passenger information and driver information). Now, with the new modifications, 'TripDetails' is an array of trips. Each index has the same information for each trip (trip information, passenger information and driver information). But now, with this new string, Android Studio gives me this error:

> of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Can a string be casted to JSONObject if it has this format? It's a valid JSON string. Here's the complete JSON: https://paste2.org/VemkLNMJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you made your json object an `array` (I don't see why since you have just 1 element). Anyway you can probably do something like this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject obj_temp = arr.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

your response starts with Array and you trying to convert it into Object.

[ represents json array node

{ represents json object node

```
JSONArray obj_temp = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonobject = obj_temp.getJSONObject(i);
String id       = jsonobject.getString("id");
String title    = jsonobject.getString("title");
String company  = jsonobject.getString("company");
String category = jsonobject.getString("category");}
```